# C++ ofstream adding random data to a file!

Tags: c++, file

Here is my code:

```
std::ifstream file2(imageToAdd.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
if(file2){
    file2.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
    length = file2.tellg();
    file2.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
    vector<char> tempImageVec(length);
    file2.read(&tempImageVec[0],length);
    int totalFileUpload=0;
    std::ofstream f("test.data");
    f << (char)1;
    totalFileUpload+=1;
    vector<char> AddImagesize=print4Bytes(length);
    for(int i=0; i<AddImagesize.size(); i+=1){
        f << (char)AddImagesize[i];
    }
    totalFileUpload+=AddImagesize.size();
    for(int i=0; i<tempImageVec.size(); i++)
        f << tempImageVec[i];
    totalFileUpload+=tempImageVec.size();
    cout << totalFileUpload << endl;
}
```

As you can see, totalFileUpload should be count the amount of data that gets put into the file, however in this case, i add a file (Around 1.33mb), the cout statement outputs: 1,405,202 bytes
However opening the fine in a program such as notepad++, or just viewing the properties of the file, shows that the file is now 1,409,439

So where did this extra 4,237 bytes come from?

The only obvious thing i could spot was the possibility of the length of the file being read being incorrect, however it is correct, as it was the same as when i viewed the properties.

Comment: you opened f in text mode that will (in windows) replace `\n` with `\r\n`

Comment: @ratchetfreak Thankyou all fixed now, i did it with the first stream, but forgot with the second haha :/

gnat I was in a hurry, i actually thought this was stackoverflow in the split second that i started this post...
my bad :P

Comment: What does `print4Bytes` do?

Comment: print4Bytes converts an int into 4 separate bytes so i can save it to a file easier.
However my question has already been fixed!